# Deploy Contract for every user

Tags: contract-development, ether, contract-design, contract-deployment

I have an application in which I have to put each user information on a different block to get the block unique address, do I have to deploy contract every time I will add new user information?

Comment: The answer suggested by you doesn't fit in my case. I have to create a unique block for every user. Can you please suggest me a good approach to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'block'?

Comment: I mean unique address for every user like when we deploy a smart contract it returns a unique address of the contract. So, It's a block for me.

Comment: Ok so by block you mean a new smart contract

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you want a factory contract. You could do it this way, but I still do suggest you use a mapping.

First, deploy the `UserFactory`contract. Each time you want to store new user information, call `createUser`. It emits the event `UserCreated`, which contains the index at which the user was stored.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

contract User {
    uint256 public id;
    bytes32 public name;
    uint8 public age;

    constructor( uint256 _id, bytes32 _name, uint8 _age) public {
        name = _name;
        id = _id;
        age = _age;
    }
}

contract UserFactory {
    User[] public users;
    function createUser(uint256 _id, bytes32 _name, uint8 _age) external {
        User user = new User(_id, _name, _age);

        emit UserCreated(user, users.length);

        users.push(user);
    }

    event UserCreated(User user, uint256 index);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Henk! I am a fresher to ethereum, I didn't know exactly what I was asking. I just figure out when I deploy a contract and then call its method using send() I am getting a blockhash, blockNumber and transaction ID in response. Is there a block is created for every transaction I do and parameter I pass to the function get stored on the new block without overriding previous user data? And how to view the data stored on that blocks? What's the difference between using this process and the one you suggested in your answer?

Comment: Maybe you should read the [Solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) before you start to create anything with it. Also, please read up on how blockchain technology actually works, as it seems you are not very familiar with the internals of Ethereum and how smart contracts are executed. You might want to check out [this video about blockchain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSo_EIwHSd4) and [this video about smart contracts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZE2HxTmxfrI)

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I'll definitely go through this. But at this moment it's kinda urgent for me. Can you please help me?

Comment: I am now adding a transaction for each set of new data and getting transaction id in return. Now, How can I see my saved data using that transaction Id?